# Unable to parse XML tag

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Here simply i'm trying to fetch json everything is working fine but have little bit problem

My XML :

```
 <match id="3" type="TEST" srs="The Ashes 2013" mchDesc="ENG vs AUS" mnum="1st Test" vcity="Nottingham" vcountry="England" grnd="Trent Bridge" inngCnt="4" datapath="http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/match/2013/2013_ASHES/ENG_AUS_JUL10_JUL14/">
  <state mchState="complete" status="England won by 14 runs" TW="Eng" decisn="Batting" addnStatus="" splStatus=""></state>
   <Tm id="9" Name="Eng" sName="ENG" flag="1"/>
   <Tm id="4" Name="Aus" sName="AUS" flag="1"/>
   <Tme Dt="Jul 10 2013" stTme="10:00" enddt="Jul 14 2013"/>
     <mscr>
        <inngsdetail noofovers="0" rrr="0" crr="2.67" cprtshp=""/>
        <btTm id="4" sName="AUS">
           <Inngs desc="2nd Inns" r="296" Decl="0" FollowOn="0" ovrs="110.5" wkts="10"/>
           <Inngs desc="1st Inns" r="280" Decl="0" FollowOn="0" ovrs="64.5" wkts="10"/>
        </btTm>
        <blgTm id="9" sName="ENG">
           <Inngs desc="2nd Inns" r="375" Decl="0" FollowOn="0" ovrs="149.5" wkts="10"/>
           <Inngs desc="1st Inns" r="215" Decl="0" FollowOn="0" ovrs="59" wkts="10"/>
        </blgTm>
       </mscr>
  </match>
```

My Code :

```
 try {
String mGetBufferData = getBufferData(Global.URL_MAIN);
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
mGetBufferData.getBytes("UTF-8"));

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(stream);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("match");
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodeList1.item(i);
    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
    mMatchType = fstElmnt.getAttribute("srs");
    if (mMatchType.equalsIgnoreCase(Global.URL_MATCH_TYPE)) {

    location = fstElmnt.getAttribute("grnd") + ","
                            + fstElmnt.getAttribute("vcity");

    mInningCount = fstElmnt.getAttribute("inngCnt");

    // Fetch state node
    NodeList idList1 = fstElmnt
                    .getElementsByTagName("state");
    Element idElement1 = (Element) idList1.item(0);

    mStatusPartial = idElement1.getAttribute("mchState");
    mStatusFull = idElement1.getAttribute("status");

    try {
        // Fetch Tm Inngs details
    NodeList idList33 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("btTm");
    for (int m = 0; m < idList33.getLength(); m++) {
    Node node4 = idList33.item(m);
    Element fourthElmnt = (Element) node4;
             arrayBettingTeamName.add(fourthElmnt.getAttribute("sName"));
    arrayType.add("betting");
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
// Fetch Tm Inngs details
NodeList idList55 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("blgTm");
for (int m = 0; m < idList55.getLength(); m++) {
    arrayType.add("bowling");
}

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    // Fetch Tm Inngs details
NodeList idList4 = fstElmnt .getElementsByTagName("Inngs");
for (int m = 0; m < idList4.getLength(); m++) {
    Node node4 = idList4.item(m);
    Element fourthElmnt = (Element) node4;
            arrayInndesc.add(fourthElmnt
                                    .getAttribute("desc"));
            arrayInnR.add(fourthElmnt.getAttribute("r"));

            arrayInnOver.add(fourthElmnt
                                    .getAttribute("ovrs"));
            arrayInnWikcet.add(fourthElmnt
                                    .getAttribute("wkts"));
                        }
            Log.e("arrayInnOver", arrayInnOver.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here i'm getting data of `Inngs` tag in single loop But what actuallt i want i also want to know it comes from `btTm` or `blgTm` , I want something like

betting = 2nd Inns (Which i'm getting)

betting = 1st Inns (Which i'm getting)

bowling=  2nd Inns (Which i'm getting)

bowling=  1st Inns (Which i'm getting)

Sosmetime `btTm` can have 2 data and `blgTm`  can have 1 data

But here i'm not getting lenth of this both tags .

Comment: Instead of giving us a screenshot of your code, can you give us the actual contents of your XML?

Comment: @Zact I need size of btTm,blgTm . Using getLength but getting 1 for each.

Comment: What? How does that have to do with giving us a [SSCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @ZachLatta i've tried my best to solve it after i've posted code

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/0v133p1V1C1e

Comment: @Zach Check it , code is updated

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33578/discussion-between-user2202964-and-zach-latta)